# How can I group and sum XML data with the following structure using LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sum, grouping

XML structure:

```
<Root>
    <Place name="Place 1">
        <Event type="Type 1">
            <Title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</Title>
            <Description>Lorem ipsum</Description>
            <People>73</People>
        </Event>

        <Event type="Type 2">
            <Title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</Title>
            <Description>Lorem ipsum</Description>
            <People>3</People>
        </Event>
    </Place>

    <Place name="Place 2">
        <Event type="Type 1">
            <Title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</Title>
            <Description>Lorem ipsum</Description>
            <People>10</People>
        </Event>

        <Event type="Type 2">
            <Title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</Title>
            <Description>Lorem ipsum</Description>
            <People>49</People>
        </Event>
    </Place>
</Root>
```

I need to group the event type across all places and get the total amount of people per type of event. All I could come up with was this:

```
var event_types = from event in data.Elements("Event").Attributes("type")
                  group event by event.Value into g
                  select g;
```

But that only does the grouping, I have absolutely no idea how to get the sum after trying for a couple of hours.

The result should look like this:

```
+------------+--------+
| Type       | People |
+------------+--------+
| Type 1     |     83 |
| Type 2     |     52 |
+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

```
var events = data.Root.Elements("Place")
    .SelectMany(p => p.Elements("Event"))
    .GroupBy(e => (string)e.Attribute("type"))
    .Select(g => new {
        Type = g.Key,
        People = g.Sum(e => Convert.ToInt32(e.Element("People").Value))
    });
```

Breaking it down, we first find all of the `Event` nodes:

```
.SelectMany(p => p.Elements("Event")) 
// returns an IEnumerable<XElement> of your four Events
```

Then we do the grouping by the attribute value:

```
.GroupBy(e => (string)e.Attribute("type"))
// returns an IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, XElement>> of two groups
```

Finally, we create the result by selecting a new anonymous type where the `Type` property is group key, and the `People` property is the sum of the values in the child `People` element (converted to an `int` first):

```
.Select(g => new {
    Type = g.Key, // "Type 1" or "Type 2"
    People = g.Sum(e => Convert.ToInt32(e.Element("People").Value))
});
// g is the IGrouping<string, XElement>. You can use the LINQ method
// Sum across each XElement (e), e being your Event.
```

And the output is as you expected:

```
+------------+--------+
| Type       | People |
+------------+--------+
| Type 1     |     83 |
| Type 2     |     52 |
+------------+--------+
```

EDIT: As shown in another answer, the lines before `.GroupBy` could be replaced with `data.Descendants("Event")` -- I overlooked that shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
var events=document.Descendants("Event")
                   .GroupBy(e=>(string)e.Attribute("type"))
                   .Select(g=>new {Type=g.Key, People=g.Sum(e=>(int)e.Element("People"))})
```